# Remove specific vertical gridline from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically I would like to remove some of the vertical gridlines in my plot. Note that this is not a duplicate of [How can I suppress the vertical gridlines in a ggplot2 plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678141/how-can-i-suppress-the-vertical-gridlines-in-a-ggplot2-plot) since this subjet is about deleting all the vertical gridlines.

Here is a minimal reproductible example :

```
ggplot(diamonds) +
  aes(x = price) + 
  geom_histogram(
    color = 'white',
    fill = 'blue4'
    ) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

I would like to supress the vertical gridline which are not associated to a label (5000, 10000, ...).

I tried :

```
p +
 theme(
   panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()
   )
```

but it actually does the opposite of what I'm looking for : It deletes the lines associated to a label, instead of the 'useless' ones.

Comment: Do `panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()`

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen sorry, didn't notice your comment while answering. You posted it 30 seconds earlier. You can post it as an answer and i'll delete mine.

Comment: no problem guys. go ahead.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `panel.grid.minor.x`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds) +
  aes(x = price) + 
  geom_histogram(
    color = 'white',
    fill = 'blue4'
  ) + 
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```